# How to literally include echo in a command?

Tags: bash, echo, sudo

In my script there's:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Take sudo password from the first argument if present
SUDO="sudo -u postgres"
if [ "$1" != "" ]; then
    SUDO="echo $1 | sudo -S -u postgres"
fi

${SUDO} psql -c "create database foo;"

... several other similar commands here ...
```

When I run the script with `myPassword` I get:

```
myPassword | sudo -S -u postgres psql -c create database foo;
```

So it just echoes the line. Obviously what I want is to literally run that command, but so that `$1` gets expanded:

`$ echo myPassword | sudo -S -u postgres psql -c create database foo;`

How can I do that?

Comment: Ideally, you should just configure `sudo` to allow the appropriate uses to run `psql` as the user `postgres` without entering a password.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pipes `|`, redirection `<` and stuff like that are not interpreted by the shell when you run a command by expanding a variable. Only words are split and globs (`*`, `?`, `[]`) are expanded. **Example:**

```
$ v='echo a | cat'
$ $v
a | cat > b
```

To interpret them, you could use `eval`

```
$ v='echo a | cat'
$ eval "$v"
a
```

However, this is frowned upon as you often end up with quoting issues. Usually, there are better ways to solve a specific problem.

As a somewhat cleaner solution you could wrap your pipe inside a function:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Take sudo password from the first argument if present
SUDO="sudo -u postgres"
if [ "$1" != "" ]; then
    pw="$1"
    sudoWithPw() { echo "$pw" | sudo -S -u postgres "$@"; }
    SUDO="sudoWithPw"
fi

${SUDO} psql -c "create database foo;"
```

An even better solution would be to login as user `postgres` only once instead of prefixing every command with `${SUDO}`. You can do so using `su` or `sudo bash -c aFunctionYouExportedEarlier`.

Comment: Thanks, that wrapper was neat and worked :)